# listctrl not populating properly

Tags: python, wxpython

So I managed to get the list of items in a given order to populate the database properly however. when converting the items to populate the listctrl widget that shows the items included in an order....... I get this:
[image]

the left window shows what happens when you add the 1st item.... right window is where my problem lies. it essentially overwrites the 1st item's text and adds a blank column instead.... the price however adds up properly and All items are properly added into the sql database... so my problem lies in how I populate my list

the code shown below is the function that populates the list ctrl shown earlier... I can't seem to find out where I went wrong... any ideas?

code for rebooting the list

```
    def refresh_list2(self, event):
          """Place the names of each ItemEntry into the list"""

        index = 0
        self.entrydict = {}
        self.list2.DeleteAllItems()
        for entry in self.ordite.list_entries():
                if entry.Order_ID == self.entry.Order_ID:
                   self.list2.InsertStringItem(index,self.entry.Order_ID)
                   self.list2.SetStringItem(index,1,self.entryit.Item_ID)
                   self.list2.SetStringItem(index,2,str(self.entryit.Item_Price))
                   self.list2.SetStringItem(index,3,str(self.entryit.Item_Qty))
                   self.entrydict[index] = entry
                   index += 1
```

code for inserting the items into the database

```
    def add_item(self, event):
        """Add a new entry to the Order_Date ite"""
        # start out with blank, generic Entry
        self.entryit = oi.OrderItemEntry(self.entry.Order_ID,"","","0")
        self.endiag = AddItemOrder(self,self.entryit)
        self.endiag.ShowModal()           


        self.ordite.add_entry(self.entry.Order_ID,
                            str(self.entryit.Item_ID),
                            str(self.entryit.Item_Price),
                            str(self.entryit.Item_Qty) )

        self.refresh_list2(None)
        self.addPrice(None)
```

still thinking of making a function in the backend that stores a filtered list of the item objects based on the given order_ID

Comment: The code shown doesn't look like it can produce the results in the gui shown. Your for loop is not using entry to fill the listctrl, each time it loops for each item in entry it is using the same self.entry and self.entryit variables.

Comment: okay... changed it so all are referring to entryit which is the object that stores the items details.... same thing happens...

Comment: @ Aya... no good nothing changed.....

Answer (score 1):

Oh, the joys of `wx.ListCtrl`. ;-)

I spent many an hour battling with those before writing a wrapper class around it to make it significantly less painful.

There a couple of problems with your `refresh_list2()` code...

First of all, the `InsertStringItem()` method will always insert the item *before* the specified `index`, so if you want to append to the list, you have to set the `index` to any value greater than or equal to than the number of items currently in the list - `sys.maxint` works quite nicely.

Secondly, the `InsertStringItem()` will return the index at which it inserted the item, so you'll have to use that value in any subsequent calls to `SetStringItem()`.

Try something like this...

```
def refresh_list2(self, event):
      """Place the names of each ItemEntry into the list"""

    self.entrydict = {}
    self.list2.DeleteAllItems()

    for entry in self.ordite.list_entries():
        if entry.Order_ID == self.entry.Order_ID:
           index = self.list2.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, self.entry.Order_ID)
           self.list2.SetStringItem(index, 1, self.entryit.Item_ID)
           self.list2.SetStringItem(index, 2, str(self.entryit.Item_Price))
           self.list2.SetStringItem(index, 3, str(self.entryit.Item_Qty))
           self.entrydict[index] = entry
```

...which should achieve the desired result, but you may later have issues with `self.entrydict` if you subsequently delete an item from the list, because the index values might change.

---

**Update**

Not sure what you're doing, but the following self-contained example works for me...

```
import sys
import wx

data = (('O0012', '1001', '235.0', '1'),
        ('O0012', '1002', '600.0', '2'))

app = wx.App(redirect=False)
frame = wx.Frame(None)
lc = wx.ListCtrl(frame, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
lc.InsertColumn(0, 'Order ID')
lc.InsertColumn(1, 'Item ID')
lc.InsertColumn(2, 'Item Price')
lc.InsertColumn(3, 'Item Qty')
for a, b, c, d in data:
    index = lc.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, a)
    lc.SetStringItem(index, 1, b)
    lc.SetStringItem(index, 2, c)
    lc.SetStringItem(index, 3, d)

frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

---

**Update #2**

Ah. I think you meant to insert the items from the local `entry` variable, rather than the instance attributes...

```
def refresh_list2(self, event):
      """Place the names of each ItemEntry into the list"""

    self.entrydict = {}
    self.list2.DeleteAllItems()

    for entry in self.ordite.list_entries():
        if entry.Order_ID == self.entry.Order_ID:
           index = self.list2.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, entry.Order_ID)
           self.list2.SetStringItem(index, 1, entry.Item_ID)
           self.list2.SetStringItem(index, 2, str(entry.Item_Price))
           self.list2.SetStringItem(index, 3, str(entry.Item_Qty))
           self.entrydict[index] = entry
```

Comment: @ Aya... any way to clear the entrydict dictionary in case I do have to delete an item?

Comment: @SeanPerez The best solution for that problem would depend on what you're using the `entrydict` for. It would help to include any portions of the code which access it - at the moment, all I can see is that you build it, but never actually use it.

Comment: @SeanPerez See updated answer, and if you have any comments, can you put them on this answer, rather than the question, otherwise I don't get notified.

Comment: well Its actually part of a bigger application working with sql. the data i'm inserting is essentially the data from the sql back end. I do know it has to do with how my refresh list inserts items given it essentially overwrites the 1st list entry and writes blanks for the rest. but said data is properly inserted in the SQL back end... I'd really rather not post all my code given it's a localized thing with my refresh_list2 function..... oddly enough it works properly when applied in my other modules and I cannot fathom why

Comment: I almost always use ObjectListView instead of ListCtrl just because its interface is much better and I think it is easier to use with a database.

Comment: I still find it quite odd......... Dunno why. I actually use the same function in terms of code for adding orders to a master list and it works perfectly fine. dunno why in the world it went out of whack when I use it here

Comment: Have you checked yet what entry is actually setting the gui values to by printing them, the gui code could be fine and its what your setting it thats out of whack.